# ui-grid column header menu not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[image]

As the photo shows, the column menu is not shown.

Here is my setting of the grid:

```
angular.module('app.ReportCtrl',['ngSanitize','ngTouch','ngCsv','ui.grid.grouping','ui.grid','ui.grid.autoResize','ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'reportFilters', 'reportDirectives', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable'])
.controller('ReportCtrl',function($http, uiGridConstants,uiGridGroupingConstants,$rootScope, $scope, $filter, $timeout, PropertyService, EventService, SearchService, FormService, DatabaseService, ReportService, $location, $locale, EventColors, $modal, $q){

$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'queryResult',
        enableSorting: true,
        showColumnFooter: true,
        enableColumnResize : true,

    };
```

html:

```
<div id="table" class="gridStyle" ui-grid='gridOptions'  ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns></div>
```

**Update**
when I click the button I get an error:

> ```
> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngFocus', can't be found!
> ```

**Update**
When I click the button, there is no item in menuitem.
[image]

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was somehow ng-Focus doesn't like one/some of my other plug-ins and I could not find out which one. So I ended up deleting the ng-Focus/ng-Blur in the menuItem template in ui-grid.js and it works for me.

Not sure whether it is a good solution or not..

Answer (score 0):

Could you Please add the columnDefs like 
eg,

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'cost', enableColumnMenu: true }
      ]};
```

Please go through this linkhttp://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro it has all concepts related to ui-grid with example's.